# I cant track events on Application Insights via Javascript

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-media-services, azure-media-player

Im currently working on a plugin for azure media player to track events like when a user starts to play a video and some stuff like that. But first of all, my events arent being tracked. I reduced the problem to the minimun and i put this in a javascript file :
`window.appInsights.trackEvent("test",{ name: "TEST" });`
this code is being executed, and the variable window.appInsights is correct too,i mean, its not undefined, but i dont see this event in the custom events section of app insights in azure (in the logs, of course). Im pretty lost, hope u can help.
thx in advance!

i have tried to track different events, i have put the trackEvent code in different parts of my code and in all of them the window.appInsights is correct,but it isnt working

Comment: Are you sure the instrumentation key / connection string is correctly set?

Comment: Yes, i can see the app insights is correctly identified in the console, and the instrumentation key is correct

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, it is resolved. if u are having this trouble its because dc.services.visualstudio.com requests are being blocked. The reason whi it didnt worked for me was becasue i didnt turn off my ad blockers. Simple and frustrating as that :,)